# jQuery selectmenu is not displaying options

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple `select` element on my page

```
<fieldset>
   <label for="speed">Select example</label>
   <select name="miktest_select" id="miktest_select">
      <option data-field-set="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
   </select>
</fieldset>
```

Using jQuery, I then do a simple `$('#miktest_select').selectmenu();`

The script creates the div element at the bottom of my page as expected

```
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-front ui-selectmenu-open" style="top: 268px; left: 539.828px;">
    <ul aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="CalculationName-button" id="CalculationName-menu" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-2" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 397px;">
    <li class="ui-state-disabled ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-disabled="true">Please select</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item ui-state-focus" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="option">Leaving Service Quote</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option">Retirement Quote</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And clicking on my select amends the class of the div to `ui-selectmenu-open`
but the `<ul>` and `<li>` items are not being displayed

[image]

When viewing the elements in Chrome Developer, I cannot see anything that is making them hidden.

My site uses the bundleConfig plugin and I am loading my JS and CSS files in the following order

```
"Scripts/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js",
"Scripts/vendor/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js",

"Content/jquery-ui.min.css",
"Content/jquery-ui-selectmenu.css",
```

Am I loading in the wrong order? My site also uses Bootstrap, could this be overwriting the selectmenu

I am at a loss as to why the values are not displaying (even though they are in the HTML on the page)

Comment: `$('#miktest_select)` should be `$('#miktest_select')`. You missed a `'`.

Comment: check your browser console and see is there any error is showing? And `$('#miktest_select).selectmenu();` need to be `$('#miktest_select').selectmenu();` (`'`missed). Is it TYPO mistake?

Comment: overflow:hidden ? or white color ?

Comment: @ProEvilz am sure the typo is only on the question as he said that the script is generating the div

Comment: Apologies for the missing single quote - it was a typo in the question and has been corrected.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - no `overflow:hidden` or `color:white` properties set

Comment: @Mike Any errors in the dev console?

Comment: It looks like a css issue. I'd try playing around with the developer console in chrome, remove all css classes and see what changes adding them back one by one

Comment: No errors - have just solved it - will put in the answer. Thanks all for your help and making me think!

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property on the `.ui-front` class was set to 100 by jquery-ui-selectmenu.css

My page had another `position:absolute` div that covered the entire page with a higher z-index value therefore was stacking on top of the selectmenu div